# How to redirect all url to https except one?

Tags: htaccess, drupal

```
# Go to https if not on firmware
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/firmware$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http if you are on firmware
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/firmware$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This code should redirect `/firmwire` to `http` instead of `https`. But `example.com/firmware` redirect to `example.com/index.php`. whats problem is going on?

The code is run on apache server and drupal 7. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # Go to http if you are on firmware
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/firmware$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
> ```
>
> This code should redirect `/firmwire` to `http` instead of `https`.

Both your code blocks redirect to HTTPS. In fact, you would expect the above to trigger a redirect loop since it is potentially redirecting to itself. That is unless `/firmware` is a physical filesystem directory - or it's not actually being processed at all?

> But `example.com/firmware` redirect to `example.com/index.php`

This suggests you have a conflict with existing directives - perhaps your redirects are in the wrong place? The order of mod_rewrite directives is important.

These directives need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` *before* the Drupal front-controller.

These directives can also be tidied a bit; no need for the additional condition that checks the URL-path. This check should be performed by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
# Go to https if not on firmware
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule !^firmware$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R,L]

# Go to http if you are on firmware
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
RewriteRule ^(firmware)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

The `NC` flag is only required if `/firmware` really can be mixed case.

If `/firmware` is a physical filesystem directory then this may need modifying (as mod_dir will, by default, append a trailing slash).